# In a software project, how would you differentiate a Component from a Module?

Tags: module, project, components

In a software, how would you differentiate a Component from a Module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that the answer depends on who you ask.

I think of the difference as being one of granularity and role. A software component to my understanding is a self-contained entity with a well-defined (and preferrably stable) interface that interacts with the remaining parts of a system, and which has significant meaning from a system architecture point of view. An example would be a data access abstraction layer.

A module to me would rather be a deployable source code bundle containing code which shares a common purpose, but doesn't perform any significant role in the system (which means replacing it would not require changes to the system's overall architecture). An example would be a JSON serializer in a web service.

Answer (score 6):

Generally speaking,

- a component is a relatively finely
  grained grouping of elements that
  serve a particular service in the
  solution.
- a module is courser    grained and
  acts as a grouping of one    or more
  related services provided by    the
  software.

A module will tend to make use of many componenents to provide its services whereas a component will likely to be constructed from a handful of classes and other components.

In any case its subjective and depends on the scale of the application.  For a small application there is likely to be a single program (a module) and a number of components.  In medium sized application there could be several modules and many components.  In a large application you might want to introduce the term sub-system which is even more courser grained than a module !

Comment: Interesting - in my experience the definitions are exactly the opposite.  Software development standards tend to use "module testing" interchangeably with "unit testing", for example.

Answer (score 4):

Modules are the capabilities of giving the software new functionality.

Components are elements

Answer (score 2):

Components are generally regarded as self-contained, pluggable items that follow some sort of software interface specification.  A good example is GUI items such as enhanced textboxes and dropdowns.  Basically anything that is not a complete program, but which can be plugged into another program to enhance its functionality.

The word Module has fallen out of favor in the past few years.  Module is a more generic term, but some languages have it as a keyword, i.e. Modula 2.  VB.NET has a Module keyword, but that is just an ordinary class with static members, and my understanding is that most VB programmers prefer to use the Class keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Components are defined at software system level (as seen/thought at runtime). They are the elements of a executing system and together compose a larger system. These components/elements interact among themselves using connectors(interfaces). Imagine black boxes communicating among themselves, no care is given to their implementation/source code.

Module is defined at the programming language level (say, set of 5 classes comprise a module providing some functionality). They are defined at source code level as per the functionality provided by that collection of code. (example: persistence classes in your application responsible for interacting with the database).

Note that, module is also a type of component (going by categorisation and shares a "is-a" association with component).

Reference: Len Bass, Software arch. in practice and [Dr. Timothy Lethbridge lecture](http://youtu.be/FMKv8Vozf5c)

Answer (score 1):

component: black-box module.

But there isn't any significant difference, really. Don't try to look for deep meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

A component is a just another name for module, they are the same thing. Usually component is the term that you can find in a software engineering book whereas module has a more widespread usage.

Comment: That is not correct. Component and module are not exactly the same thing. Although, often incorrectly used interchangeably.